# Is $L:=\{a^k \mid k \text{ is prime}\}$ regular?

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

For this exercise the pumping lemma should be used. My instructor gave me a tip it should start with $w:= a^{prime(n)}$ where prime is a while program returning the nth prime number. This does make sense to me since a while program always returns an element of the integers. How can I use code in my proof?

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need any code. If S is any set of integers such that the difference between neighbouring elements becomes arbitrary large, then $\{a^k: k \in S\}$ is non-regular.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how the hint could be useful in applying the pumping lemma except from the fact that there are infinitely many prime numbers. So you start by a picking a word $w$ of the form $a^r$, where $r$ is a prime that is greater than the pumping constant. Then, think how many times you need to pump in order to get a word of the form $a^k$, where $k$ is non-prime. Hint: $k$ is not prime iff it can be written as $k_1\cdot k_2$, where $k_1, k_2 \notin \{1, k\}$.

Comment: Well if I can choose a $|xy| \leq n$ where $n:=|w|$ dependent on the particular prime number I can choose $y$ to be a and if I choose i to be $2$ then my string of a's must be even In other words not a prime number.

Comment: You cannot choose y as you like. The pumping lemma suggests that **there exists**  a partition into $xyz$ such that the 3 conditions of the lemma hold. The 3 conditions are not guaranteed to hold **for every** partition.

Comment: If you didn't take the contrapositive into consideration.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, can you be more concrete? Do you understand now why your suggestion breaks? If not, I will be glad to help.

Comment: $\begin{array}{l}  \neg(((\exists n\in\mathbb N^+)((\forall w \in L)((|w|\geq n) \\ \Rightarrow ((\exists x,y,z \in \Sigma^\ast)(w=xyz \land (|y|\geq 1\land |xy|\leq n\land(\forall i\geq 0)(xy^iz \in L)))))) \Rightarrow L\notin \textbf{REG}_\Sigma \end{array}$ so the quantifiers turn right?

Comment: Right, but you used it uncorrectly. You have to consider every partition in order to conclude that $L$ is not regular, and you only considered partitions with $|y|=1$. You need to show the following for every parition $w=xyz$: if $|y|\geq 1 \wedge |xy|\leq n$, then $\exists i$ such that $xy^iz \notin L$.

Comment: The pumping lemma suggests that there is a partition that satisfies the three conditions. You showed that all partitions with $|y|=1$ cannot satisfy the three conditions. What about partitions with $|y|>1$? Who knows, maybe there is a partition with $|y|>1$ that satisfy the three conditions?

Comment: I do understand now that I can only choose w and I need to find a pattern that will contradict at least one of the three conditions if I change i to anything in  $\{ 0 \dots n\}$, but how did i do the contrapositive wrong exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118309/discussion-between-bader-abu-radi-and-phistackoverflow).